# How to use @FetchRequest with a SortDescriptor based on a NSNumber var

Tags: swiftui, core-data

I'm trying to use this @FetchRequest wrapper.

```
@FetchRequest(sortDescriptors: [SortDescriptor(\.artist), SortDescriptor(\.year)])
```

The `artist` property used to be a `NSString?` var and it didn't build until I changed it to `String?` for the SortDescriptor.

But the `year` is a `NSNumber?` and I cannot just change the @NSManaged var to `Int?` because it complains that it cannot be represented in Obj-C.

A computed var that produces a String version of the year doesn't work either. It builds but then it crashes because Obj-C can't see it.

How can I sort based on a `NSNumber`?

Comment: Did you try Int64 (or Int32,…) instead of Int?

Comment: Yes, I already got it to work that way, I will answer my question

Answer (score 0):

The trick was to have it as an Int16 (being Int16 enough for a year property), and have it as a non optional. It works for me to take the value 0 as data unavailable instead of having nil as before, so it took a few additional adjustments for that.

Fortunately this change doesn't require any sort of DB migration. The data model already defined this property as Integer 16.